# How to hide/show and image or textField on last page?

Tags: jasper-reports

In Jasper studio how can I disable/show background for a single page in the report.

I want to disable the watermark image which I set in the background for the last page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method that I know when you need to compare current page towards totale number of pages is to use evaluation type "auto" on the element.

From [EvaluationTimeEnum](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/EvaluationTimeEnum.html#AUTO)

> Variables will be evaluated at a time corresponding to their reset type.

**Solution** adapted from lucianc's answer at https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/514622/print-when-last-page

Create a variabile that contains current page having reset type Page (so it's evaluate when Auto as current page number)

```
 <variable name="currentPageInAutoEval" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Page">
    <variableExpression>$V{PAGE_NUMBER}</variableExpression>
 </variable
```

set evaluation time to "Auto" on your element (textField, image etc) and in expression use [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

In your case, no image on last page it would be

```
<image evaluationTime="Auto">
    <imageExpression>$V{currentPageInAutoEval}.equals($V{PAGE_NUMBER}) ? null : yourImage</imageExpression>
</image>
```

Hence with `evalutationTime="Auto"` `$V{currentPageInAutoEval}` will be evaluated as resetType (Page) to current page number and `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` as the total number of pages.

Comment: Isn't it possible to move that evaluation into the printWhen field?

Comment: @metters No it is not possibile because the  "print when" expression does not have delayed evaluation. You need to use a ternary expression in imageExpression.